# how to include a class which is not a model in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have added class ContactRequest in `home_helper.rb`

```
module HomeHelper

    class ContactRequest
        include ActiveModel::Model

        attr_accessor :name, :email, :phone, :message, :captcha

        validates :name, presence: true,length: {in:2..255}
        validates :email, presence: true, length: {in:6..255}
        validates :message, presence: true
        validates :phone, presence: true
        validates :captcha, presence: true
    end

end
```

This class basically is to be used to bind dat from a JSON POST to an object which then I can use for

1. Verifying Captcha
2. Sending the contact information from this object as an email via SendGrid

hence, I do not have any needs to persist the information.

However I get an error when the relevant method of the controller is called

```
  def contact
    @contactReq = ContactRequest.new(JSON.parse(params[:json]))

    logger.debug "ContactRequest: #{@contactReq.attributes.inspect}"
```

for this line I see in the logs

```
NameError (uninitialized constant HomeController::ContactRequest):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:6:in `contact'
```

isn't the home_helper available to the view and this controller? Or should I put this class in concerns directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the module name in front of the classname `HomeHelper`:

```
def contact
  @contactReq = HomeHelper::ContactRequest.new(JSON.parse(params[:json]))
  ...
end
```